# Why does the length of a textview determine the position of other elements in android?

Tags: android

I have the following xml file to define my layout for an activity in android:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

    android:columnCount="10"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/new_title"
        android:textSize="32dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/textTitleEdit"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/new_descr"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="8"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/textSubTitleEdit"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/new_name"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />
    <EditText
        android:ems="7"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:id="@+id/new_name"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/clear_line"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:minHeight="15dp"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:maxWidth="15dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/new_search"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:minHeight="15dp"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:maxWidth="15dp"
        />


    _____________

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/new_label"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />



    <EditText
        android:ems="7"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:id="@+id/new_label"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    ______

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="@string/new_price"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

    <EditText
        android:ems="7"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/new_price"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="@string/new_offset"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_row="6" />

    <EditText
        android:ems="7"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/new_offset"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:id="@+id/seek_offset"
        android:layout_column="1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />



    <Button
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/new_cancel"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/new_ok"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:layout_column="8"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

This works fine, and I see something like in the following image (although I might have defined nonesense in this xml, or something incorrect, as I am a beginning beginner in Android...)

[image]

However, I am reusing this layout in some other activity and replace the text of the `textView` with the id `textSubTitleEdit` by a shorter text. As a consequence, the `Ok`-Button is shifted to the left, and is no longer at its place in the lower right corner.

Is there something wrong with my layout? How can the length of a `TextView` affect the position of a button?

Comment: What don't you just define seperate layout for gridview instead of nesting views instead gridview.

Comment: I am not sure what you try to suggest...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using a `GridLayout` to place all your views in the layout.

If you want your buttons to stick to the bottom, one on each side of the screen, you may consider adding a `RelativeLayout` above your `GridLayout`, and move your button there as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/new_cancel"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="10"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitleEdit"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/new_title"
        android:textSize="32dip"/>

    ....

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_offset"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:max="10"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="4"
        />

</GridLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/new_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="Cancel"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/new_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:text="Ok"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But now all the other text fields etc. are shifted to the left. Like example, the text "Label" is directly on the left side, and it does not look nice...

Comment: Well you could add a margin to your GridLayout. I will update the code for an example